# NullReferenceException in deleted entity after performing a Remove

Tags: entity-framework-core

In an otherwise functional update function, if I attempt to remove an entity which represents an optional relationship between two BusAppl entities

```
_context.BusApplDpndncy.Remove(toRemove);
```

This setter in BusApplDpndncy is called when I call SaveChanges, and passed a null value, resulting in NullReferenceException.

```
public BusAppl BusAppl
{
    set
    {
        this._BusApplName = value.BusApplNm;
        this._BusAppl = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return this._BusAppl;
    }
}
```

I'm unsure why this happens.  I want to delete the BusApplDpndncy in its entirety so it seems odd to me that it's even bothering to set a property in that object in the first place.  As far as the database schema goes, the BusAppl property is required.  I'm not sure why the framework would attempt to set it null.

From the context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BusApplDpndncy>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.BusApplId, e.DepBusApplId });

        entity.ToTable("BUS_APPL_DPNDNCY");

        entity.Property(e => e.BusApplId).HasColumnName("BUS_APPL_ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.DepBusApplId).HasColumnName("DEP_BUS_APPL_ID");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.BusAppl)
            .WithMany(p => p.BusApplDpndncyBusAppl)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.BusApplId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_BUS_APPL_DPNDNCY_NEW_BUS_APPL");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.DepBusAppl)
            .WithMany(p => p.BusApplDpndncyDepBusAppl)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepBusApplId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_BUS_APPL_DPNDNCY_NEW_BUS_APPL1");
    });
```

Comment: Could you please please clear your question in simple language, it’s not clear.

Comment: calling _context.BusApplDpndncy.Remove() causes this property assignment (this._BusApplName = value.BusApplNm;) in BusApplDpndncy to be passed a null value when SaveChanges is called.

Comment: Your setter is not null-safe.

Comment: This was auto generated EF code.  Right, the property is being accessed in a way that when the value passed in is null it breaks.  That was why  my question was about why a null is being passed in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong, but I rewrote the code realizing I had to always lookup entites within the context rather than using ones that were obtained from web api input.

The problem went away after I did that.  Still don't know why given the model it would pass a null in there though.